# find_elements_by_xpath that do not contains 3 times a specific string

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have used this code but I want to remove those links where it appears the string 'vs' three times in the link, it only has to appear one time:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/president/us/general_election')][not(@href = following::a/@href)]")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

[image]

**Update**:
I have realised that some of my code is not working as I expected, I used the code : `[not(@href = following::a/@href)]` to remove repeated href but there is still one href that is repeated. Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/president/us/general_election')][not(@href = following::a/@href)]")
for elem in elems:
    if elem.get_attribute("href").count("vs") == 1: print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

Answer (score 1):

To get link with only one occurrence of `"_vs_"` in `@href` you can extend your XPath with predicate

```
[not(contains(substring-after(@href, "_vs_"), "_vs_"))]
```

Your final XPath will be

```
"//a[contains(@href, '/president/us/general_election') and not(contains(substring-after(@href, "_vs_"), "_vs_")) and not(@href = following::a/@href)]"
```